# Program or library to handle massive numbers

Tags: java, python, math

I am looking for some way to handle numbers that are in the tens of millions of digits and can do math at this level. I can use Java and a bit of Python. So a library for one of these would be handy, but a program that can handle these kind of numbers would also work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with BigInteger and BigDecimal to look for a library fo kinds of jabs java can do with this datatypes?

Comment: Would playing with `sys.maxint` help?

Comment: What's your problem domain? I struggle to think of practical applications that need both numbers of that magnitude *and* total accuracy.

Comment: I'm guessing something cryptography .. :)

Comment: It should also give plenty of time to tell the boss "but it's calculating, still!". I tried to figure the time needed to sum two addends each of ten millions of digits but I lost count.

Answer (score 5):

For Java, take a look at the built-in classes [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). `BigInteger` numbers are limited in size by available memory. `BigDecimal` can represent arbitrarily large base-10 numbers with up to 2<sup>32</sup> digits to the right of the decimal point (in practical terms, also limited by available memory).

Both of these are limited to fairly elementary math operations. (Arithmetic, integer powers, etc. No roots, logs, etc.) If you need something more than this, consult the list of libraries at the [Java Numerics page of NIST](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/). (The [Apfloat package](http://www.apfloat.org/) supports arbitrary-precision transcendental functions and complex math.)

Answer (score 5):

Python can handle big numbers without needing any libraries.

```
>>> 100 ** 100
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L
```

Though as suggested by others you may want to use [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) if you want extra speed.

---

In Java you can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: But this number isn't 10s of millions of digits long

Comment: inspectorG4dget: Well of course I did try to post an example with tens of millions of digits first but then StackOverflow said the post was too long, so I did a shorter example instead. But I think you *should* be able to get the point. Use a bit of imagination, please.

Comment: Have you tried something like `10**10000000 + 1`?

Comment: `1e999` = `inf` in python shell (tested 2.7 and 3).

Comment: @RobW because 1e999 is parsed as a float, not an int

Comment: There's also GMPY. GMP for Python. Might be faster.

Comment: @Junuxx Then take `a = 100 ** 100000`, which results in quite a large number which can be calculated with, etc. So I don't see how it doesn't hold.

Comment: @glglgl: That number has 200,000 digits, not tens of millions. I told Python to calculate `10**10000000 + 1` 15 minutes ago, it's still thinking.

Comment: Junuux: `x=10**1000;y=x**100;z=y**100` works fine. On my computer it takes a few seconds.

Comment: @MarkByers: It seems it hangs on *printing* such huge numbers then. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529569/print-extremely-large-long-in-scientific-notation-in-python) might be relevant then.

Comment: @Junuxx: Yes: Python's binary-to-decimal conversions use quadratic-time algorithms.  If you're dealing with numbers this big, you should probably go with something like gmpy instead.

Answer (score 2):

For Python, I recommend [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/), a Python wrapper for the [GNU Bignum library](http://gmplib.org/).  While Python does *in theory* handle arbitrarily large integers (limited only by memory), and it's fine for numbers of a few thousand digits or so, it's not really that well suited to dealing with million-digit ints.  It doesn't use state-of-the-art algorithms for fast multiplication, digit conversion and other standard operations.  `gmpy` in contrast is designed to handle numbers of that sort of magnitude.

Here are some sample timings, showing that even for a few thousand digits `gmpy` is substantially faster than Python's builtin longs:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "from gmpy import mpz" "str(mpz(10)**10000)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 575 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "str(10**10000)"
100 loops, best of 3: 11.8 msec per loop
```

An aside: at some point, one of the Python core developers tried replacing Python's long integer implementation with one that used GMP directly.  It turned out that it actually slowed Python down for everyday non-huge-integer use cases.  See http://bugs.python.org/issue1814 for the details.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal should be good enough. However, you can take a look at [JScience](http://www.jscience.org/)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of math operations do you need?

Java already provides classes like java.math.BigDecimal or java.math.BigInteger you can use to do basic stuff (addition, multiplication, etc.)